# vi keep only first 10 characters of a column

Tags: vim, awk, sed

how do i do this in vi?

```
awk -F"," awk '{print substr($1,1,10)}'
```

I only want to keep the first 10 characters of my date column (example 2014-01-01) and not include the timestamp.

I tried to do it in awk but i got this error:

```
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

I believe it is a bash_profile setting error.

This is what i have in my bash_profile:

```
#export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
#export LOCALE=UTF-8

export LC_CTYPE=C
export LANG=C
```

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that `awk` produced the error message `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`. Clean up your question to be accurate and show sample input AND expected output. Why do you want to do this in `vi` anyway?

Comment: If you have troubles with your locale, you can try `LC_ALL=C awk '{print substr($0,1,10)}' file >output`.

Answer (score 10):

in vim, do:

```
:%norm! 11|D
```

this will affect all lines in your buffer.

If you like, `:s` could do this job too.

Comment: where do u specify the column?

Comment: @jxn There's a magic number `11` in the command above.  What could that possible mean?

Comment: Perhaps in given context `10l`is easier than `11|`

Comment: This is so useful... and I can't believe I haven't used it that much only because I forgot about this :-o

Comment: @jxh `:h |` you will see

Comment: what is the difference between :%norm! 11|D and :%norm 11|D?

Comment: @BenSchwehn `!` ignore mappings. it is clearly written in doc. Read `:h :norm`

Answer (score 6):

```
:%s/.\{,10}\zs.*//
```

---

- `:%s/`: apply the substitution to all the lines
- `.\{,10}`: match anything up to 10 times (greedy)
- `\zs`: indicates the beginning of the match
- `.*`: match the rest of the line
- `/`: end of the first part of `:s`
- `/`: end of the second part of `s` (since there's nothing between the two `/`, replace with nothing, ie delete)

Answer (score 4):

For editing blocks of text there is a `-- VISUAL BLOCK --` mode accessible via `CTRL-V` (on Windows ussually `CTRL-Q`). Then you can press <kbd>d</kbd> to delete your selection.

Or with a simple substitute command

```
:%s/\%>10c.*//
```

- `\%>10c` - matches after tenth column
- `.` - matches any single character but not an end-of-line
- `*` - matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as many as possible

Or you can use range

```
:1,3s/\%>10c.*//
```

This would substitute for the first three lines.